# Getting "attempt to apply non-function" to simple filtering function in RStudio

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm a complete newbie trying to teach myself to code in R. I took an introductory R course, but it doesn't seem to have helped a ton.

I'm trying to create a dataframe from a table I'm accessing via a Snowflake database connection. The connection is working from what I can tell (it shows up in my connections and environment). The entire table is huge, so I'm trying to only capture the rows with a diagnosis matching the list of diagnosis codes I've loaded into the environment. I keep getting an error when using code that a coworker gave me.

I guarantee it's something stupid and simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I used the code below and got the following error, which to me says the reference to the local table of diagnosis codes is working. However, something seems to be not working with the reference to the column in the Snowflake table (HISTOLOGY_CD)?

```
bc_cr_gen <- tbl(snow_con,"REGISTRY_GENERAL") %>%
   filter(HISTOLOGY_CD %>% local(BC_Diagnosis_Codes$Histology_Dx_Code), na.rm=TRUE) %>%
   collect()
Error in HISTOLOGY_CD %>% c("85003", "85233", "85413", "85243", "85203",  : 
  attempt to apply non-function
```

Comment: Nevermind. Somewhere along the line the %in% got changed to %>%. Solved.